# How to get current time and date in Android

Tags: android, date, time

How can I get the current time and date in an Android app?

Comment: 43 answers! While many of them were good when they were written, the good answer to use in 2018 is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168941/5772882).

Comment: @OleV.V. How about in 2023?

Comment: @user16217248, I still recommend [the answer by Basil Bourque that I linked to earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36168941/5772882).

Answer (score 1516, accepted):

You could use:

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

There are plenty of constants in Calendar for everything you need.

Check the [Calendar class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html).

Comment: +1 This was very helpful.  Being new it's all these little tidbits we need ... I'm using Calendar to get the Julian date.  Much easier than getting milliseconds and figuring out if the value equals today ;)

Comment: But where does this pull the date and time from? the android device setting itself?

Comment: @Kyle Yes, it's based on the device time settings/timezone. Quote from the [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html): *"Calendar's getInstance method returns a calendar whose locale is based on **system settings** and whose time fields have been initialized with the current date and time"* - (above the first samplecode line in the class documentation).

Comment: This just gives me the current second, between 0 and 60. Has something changed in the past couple years?

Comment: As @adamdport says, this doesn't actually answer the question...
`Calendar.getInstance().getTime()` or `Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()` will work.

Comment: can we use "new Date()" class and format with SimpleDateFormat class?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now legacy, supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & Java 7 in the [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project. Further adapted for earlier Android in the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: great, that was really helpful, you are awesome, greatest of all, thanks!

Comment: Right now this method is deprecated. In docs you can find a new solution: Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) if you need to get the only hour, or Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE) etc.

Comment: Does someone know how this compares to `new Date()`?

Comment: with format `String bugun = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());`

Answer (score 500):

You can (*but no longer should* - see below!) use [android.text.format.Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html):

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

From the reference linked above:

> The Time class is a faster replacement
>   for the java.util.Calendar and
>   java.util.GregorianCalendar classes.
>   An instance of the Time class
>   represents a moment in time, specified
>   with second precision.

---

**NOTE 1:**
It's been several years since I wrote this answer,
and it is about an old, Android-specific and now deprecated class.
Google now [says](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) that
"[t]his class has a number of issues and it is recommended that [GregorianCalendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) is used instead".

---

**NOTE 2:** Even though the `Time` class has a `toMillis(ignoreDaylightSavings)` method, this is merely a convenience to pass to methods that expect time in milliseconds. The time value is **only precise to one second**; the milliseconds portion is always `000`.  If in a loop you do

```
Time time = new Time();   time.setToNow();
Log.d("TIME TEST", Long.toString(time.toMillis(false)));
... do something that takes more than one millisecond, but less than one second ...
```

The resulting sequence will repeat the same value, such as `1410543204000`, until the next second has started, at which time `1410543205000` will begin to repeat.

Comment: @InsanityOnABun and Muhammad Babar.  No, no, no. Docs say **"specified with second precision"** Even the simplest test (getting current time in a loop, toMillis, and logging/printing the result) would have showed you that the resulting time has 000 as the millisecond part!

Comment: @IgorZelaya If you want millisecond accuracy, you are probably doing **interval timing**, rather than time of day. Android docs recommend `SystemClock.uptimeMillis()` for interval timing. Since that is what most built-in functions use, there is strong motivation for it to be well-implemented on all devices. See discussion in [SystemClock](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html)...  If you want to correlate that with time of day, in app's onResume, read both this, and Time/setToNow/toMillis. Remember the difference between those.

Comment: [Do not use the Time class](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=76439). It's going to be removed in the future and has many issues with it.

Comment: > This class was deprecated in API level 22. Use GregorianCalendar instead.  

See [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html)

Comment: Actually, `GregorianCalendar` was supplanted years ago in Java and in later Android by the *java.time* classes, specifically [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). For earlier Android, see the *ThreeTen-Backport* and *ThreeTenABP* projects.

Answer (score 447):

If you want to get the date and time in a specific pattern you can use the following:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault());
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Or,

**Date**:

```
String currentDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

**Time:**

```
String currentTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
```

Comment: Beware, SimpleDateFormat can be problematic if performance is an issue.  In my app I had a custom view that had about 20 HH:MM labels that represented specific times (long integers holding milliseconds), and an equal number of drawable resources.  Initial testing showed the interaction was not as fluid as I wanted.  When I profiled onDraw() I found that the SimpleTimeFormatter calls were taking 80% of the time.  In fact, I'm reading this page as part of a search for a more efficient formatter and to learn more about Calendars, etc.

Comment: @William T. Mallard : Were you creating new instance of `SimpleDateFormat` inside `onDraw()` ??

Comment: Yes, but no longer.  I didn't realize the overhead involved and had assumed that it was pretty much a POJO.

Comment: In short: `String currentDateandTime = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date());`

Comment: you can insert `sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())` in the middle

Comment: Even Better SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss dd/MM/yyyy ").format(Date()) 
 Result: 11:26:16 26/05/2020

Comment: @HiteshSahu You must include the Locale.getDefault bro..

Answer (score 256):

For those who might rather prefer a customized format, you can use:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy, HH:mm");
String date = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Whereas you can have DateFormat patterns such as:

```
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" ---- 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" ----------- 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"------- Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"------- 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"-------------------- 010704120856-0700
"K:mm a, z" ----------------------- 0:08 PM, PDT
"h:mm a" -------------------------- 12:08 PM
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy" ---------------- Wed, Jul 4, '01
```

Answer (score 129):

Actually, it's safer to set the current timezone set on the device with `Time.getCurrentTimezone()`, or else you will get the current time in UTC.

```
Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
today.setToNow();
```

Then, you can get all the date fields you want, like, for example:

```
textViewDay.setText(today.monthDay + "");             // Day of the month (1-31)
textViewMonth.setText(today.month + "");              // Month (0-11)
textViewYear.setText(today.year + "");                // Year 
textViewTime.setText(today.format("%k:%M:%S"));  // Current time
```

See [android.text.format.Time](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/Time.html) class for all the details.

**UPDATE**

As many people are pointing out, Google says this class has a number of issues and is not supposed to be used anymore:

> This class has a number of issues and it is recommended that
>   GregorianCalendar is used instead.
>
> Known issues:
>
> For historical reasons when performing time calculations all
>   arithmetic currently takes place using 32-bit integers. This limits
>   the reliable time range representable from 1902 until 2037.See the
>   wikipedia article on the Year 2038 problem for details. Do not rely on
>   this behavior; it may change in the future. Calling
>   switchTimezone(String) on a date that cannot exist, such as a wall
>   time that was skipped due to a DST transition, will result in a date
>   in 1969 (i.e. -1, or 1 second before 1st Jan 1970 UTC). Much of the
>   formatting / parsing assumes ASCII text and is therefore not suitable
>   for use with non-ASCII scripts.

Comment: Time should be imported from which package ?

Comment: This class was deprecated in API level 22. We can use GregorianCalendar instead.

Answer (score 102):

### tl;dr

```
Instant.now()  // Current moment in UTC.
```

…or…

```
ZonedDateTime.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) )  // In a particular time zone
```

### Details

The other answers, while correct, are outdated. The old date-time classes have proven to be poorly designed, confusing, and troublesome.

#### java.time

Those old classes have been supplanted by the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework.

- Java 8 and later: The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built-in.
- Java 7 & 6: Use the [backport of java.time](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- Android: Use this [wrapped version of that backport](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

These new classes are inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, defined by [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), and extended by the [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project.

See the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

#### `Instant`

An [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with resolution up to [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
 Instant instant = Instant.now(); // Current moment in UTC.
```

### Time Zone

Apply a time zone ([`ZoneId`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html)) to get a [`ZonedDateTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). If you omit the time zone your JVM’s current default time zone is implicitly applied. Better to specify explicitly the desired/expected time zone.

Use [proper time zone names](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in the format of `continent/region` such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Europe/Brussels`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Brussels), or [`Asia/Kolkata`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asia/Kolkata). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviations such as `EST` or `IST` as they are neither standardized nor unique.

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ); // Or "Asia/Kolkata", "Europe/Paris", and so on.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant( instant , zoneId );
```

[image: Table of date-time types in Java, both modern and legacy]

#### Generating Strings

You can easily generate a `String` as a textual representation of the date-time value. You can go with a standard format, your own custom format, or an automatically localized format.

#### ISO 8601

You can call the `toString` methods to get text formatted using the common and sensible [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard.

```
String output = instant.toString();
```

> 2016-03-23T03:09:01.613Z

Note that for `ZonedDateTime`, the `toString` method extends the ISO 8601 standard by appending the name of the time zone in square brackets. Extremely useful and important information, but not standard.

> 2016-03-22T20:09:01.613-08:00[America/Los_Angeles]

#### Custom format

Or specify your own particular formatting pattern with the [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a" );
```

Specify a [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) for a human language (English, [French](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/French_language), etc.) to use in translating the name of day/month and also in defining cultural norms such as the order of year and month and date. Note that `Locale` has nothing to do with time zone.

```
formatter = formatter.withLocale( Locale.US ); // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH or such.
String output = zdt.format( formatter );
```

#### Localizing

Better yet, let java.time do the work of localizing automatically.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.MEDIUM );
String output = zdt.format( formatter.withLocale( Locale.US ) );  // Or Locale.CANADA_FRENCH and so on.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes. Hibernate 5 & JPA 2.2 support *java.time*.

Where can the java.time classes be obtained?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - [**Java 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) brought some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android (26+) bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the process of [*API desugaring*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support#library-desugaring) brings a [subset of the *java.time*](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) functionality not originally built into Android.

    - If the desugaring does not offer what you need, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above) to Android. See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table listing which implementation of the java.time technology to use on which versions of Java and Android.]

Comment: @giraffe.guru Reread my Answer. You missed the third bullet. Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

Comment: `Instant.now()` and `ZonedDateTime.now()` is required API 26

Comment: @Ryde As I said to giraffe.guru, reread my Answer. Look for third bullet mentioning  "Android".

Comment: I believe that you are right: your new java.time edition table conveys the message more directly and easily than a bullet list. If that were me I think I’d complicate matters just a little further and put a check mark in brackets (or something similar) under ThreeTenBackport/Java 8+ and also under ThreeTenABP/Android 26+ since these combinations do work, only there isn’t usually any point in using them. Android apps being developed that use ThreeTenABP and target a range of Android API levels both over and under level 26. It seems to me that the developers choose well in these cases.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thank you for suggesting a secondary check mark in the graphic table. I have been using that in later versions of the table. Much improved.

Answer (score 85):

For the current date and time, use:

```java
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Which outputs:

```
Feb 27, 2012 5:41:23 PM
```

Comment: i got the the current date,day and time of the system but time is not changing.i wnat to increase time seconds by seconds.how can i do?

Comment: This is the recommended way of doing it, according to the Android API: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getDateTimeInstance() Thanks!

Answer (score 65):

Try with the following way. All formats are given below to get the date and time formats.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    String datetime = dateformat.format(c.getTime());
    System.out.println(datetime);
```

[image: First]

[image: Second]

[image: Third]

Answer (score 58):

To ge the current time you can use `System.currentTimeMillis()` which is standard in Java. Then you can use it to create a date

```
Date currentDate = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
```

And as mentioned by others to create a time

```
Time currentTime = new Time();
currentTime.setToNow();
```

Comment: No need for `System.currentTimeMillis()`; simply `new Date()` [does the same thing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date()).

Comment: @Jonik `Cannot resolve constructor Date()` in android, the Android SDK uses a mixture of Java 6 and 7.

Comment: @mghhgm No, `new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())` in not right: (a) it is redundant, as that is the exact same as `new Date()`. (b) The troublesome `java.util.Date` class is now supplanted by [`java.time.Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) as of Java 8 and later. Back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, and to earlier Android (<26) in *ThreeTenABP*.

Answer (score 39):

You can use the code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Output:

```
2014-11-11 00:47:55
```

You also get some more formatting options for `SimpleDateFormat` from [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html).

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 34):

Easy. You can dissect the time to get separate values for current time, as follows:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

int millisecond = cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

// 12-hour format
int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR);

// 24-hour format
int hourofday = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
```

Same goes for the date, as follows:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

int dayofyear = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int dayofweek = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
int dayofmonth = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
```

Answer (score 28):

```
SimpleDateFormat databaseDateTimeFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss");
SimpleDateFormat databaseDateFormate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
SimpleDateFormat sdf1 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' hh:mm:ss z");
SimpleDateFormat sdf3 = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM d, ''yy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf4 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
SimpleDateFormat sdf5 = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");
SimpleDateFormat sdf6 = new SimpleDateFormat("H:mm:ss:SSS");
SimpleDateFormat sdf7 = new SimpleDateFormat("K:mm a,z");
SimpleDateFormat sdf8 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa");


String currentDateandTime = databaseDateTimeFormate.format(new Date());     //2009-06-30 08:29:36
String currentDateandTime = databaseDateFormate.format(new Date());     //2009-06-30
String currentDateandTime = sdf1.format(new Date());     //30.06.09
String currentDateandTime = sdf2.format(new Date());     //2009.06.30 AD at 08:29:36 PDT
String currentDateandTime = sdf3.format(new Date());     //Tue, Jun 30, '09
String currentDateandTime = sdf4.format(new Date());     //8:29 PM
String currentDateandTime = sdf5.format(new Date());     //8:29
String currentDateandTime = sdf6.format(new Date());     //8:28:36:249
String currentDateandTime = sdf7.format(new Date());     //8:29 AM,PDT
String currentDateandTime = sdf8.format(new Date());     //2009.June.30 AD 08:29 AM
```

Date format Patterns

```
G   Era designator (before christ, after christ)
y   Year (e.g. 12 or 2012). Use either yy or yyyy.
M   Month in year. Number of M's determine length of format (e.g. MM, MMM or MMMMM)
d   Day in month. Number of d's determine length of format (e.g. d or dd)
h   Hour of day, 1-12 (AM / PM) (normally hh)
H   Hour of day, 0-23 (normally HH)
m   Minute in hour, 0-59 (normally mm)
s   Second in minute, 0-59 (normally ss)
S   Millisecond in second, 0-999 (normally SSS)
E   Day in week (e.g Monday, Tuesday etc.)
D   Day in year (1-366)
F   Day of week in month (e.g. 1st Thursday of December)
w   Week in year (1-53)
W   Week in month (0-5)
a   AM / PM marker
k   Hour in day (1-24, unlike HH's 0-23)
K   Hour in day, AM / PM (0-11)
z   Time Zone
```

Comment: Although other answers are correct too. I liked this answer as it helps related time related problems too. Thanks @Vighnesh KM

Answer (score 22):

For the current date and time with format, use:

**In Java**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
Log.d("Date", "DATE: " + strDate)
```

**In Kotlin**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    val current = LocalDateTime.now()
    val formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy. HH:mm:ss")
    var myDate: String =  current.format(formatter)
    Log.d("Date", "DATE: " + myDate)
} else {
    var date = Date()
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mma")
    val myDate: String = formatter.format(date)
    Log.d("Date", "DATE: " + myDate)
}
```

***Date formatter patterns***

```
"yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z" ---- 2001.07.04 AD at 12:08:56 PDT
"hh 'o''clock' a, zzzz" ----------- 12 o'clock PM, Pacific Daylight Time
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"------- Wed, 4 Jul 2001 12:08:56 -0700
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"------- 2001-07-04T12:08:56.235-0700
"yyMMddHHmmssZ"-------------------- 010704120856-0700
"K:mm a, z" ----------------------- 0:08 PM, PDT
"h:mm a" -------------------------- 12:08 PM
"EEE, MMM d, ''yy" ---------------- Wed, Jul 4, '01
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting co contribute. Are you contributing something that isn’t already in the previous 36 answers? In any case you are still using the notoriously troublesome and long outdated `SimpleDateFormat` class. Even before Oreo you don’t need to, you may instead use [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), the backport of java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

Answer (score 17):

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

textView.setText("" + mDay + "-" + mMonth + "-" + mYear);
```

Comment: That is only a half answer. The question was "How can I get the current time and date?"

Answer (score 16):

This is a method that will be useful to get date and time:

```
private String getDate(){
    DateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    String date=dfDate.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    DateFormat dfTime = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String time = dfTime.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    return date + " " + time;
}
```

You can call this method and get the current date and time values:

```
2017/01//09 19:23
```

Comment: I don't like the tight coupling of presentation logic and process logic; I'd prefer a method that just does the formatting & takes a date input param. I also don't understand why you're using 2 `SimpleDateFormat`s & 2 `Date`s... can't you just use `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"` as the format & call calendar once?

Answer (score 13):

If you need the current date:

```
Calendar cc = Calendar.getInstance();
int year = cc.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int month = cc.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int mDay = cc.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println("Date", year + ":" + month + ":" + mDay);
```

If you need the current time:

```
 int mHour = cc.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
 int mMinute = cc.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
 System.out.println("time_format" + String.format("%02d:%02d", mHour , mMinute));
```

Answer (score 12):

You can also use android.os.SystemClock.
For example SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() will give you more accurate time readings when the phone is asleep.

Answer (score 12):

Use:

```
Time time = new Time();
time.setToNow();
System.out.println("time: " + time.hour + ":" + time.minute);
```

This will give you, for example, "12:32".

Remember to `import android.text.format.Time;`.

Answer (score 12):

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    System.out.println("time => " + dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

    String time_str = dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());

    String[] s = time_str.split(" ");

    for (int i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
         System.out.println("date  => " + s[i]);
    }

    int year_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[0].split("/")[0]);
    int month_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[0].split("/")[1]);
    int day_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[0].split("/")[2]);

    int hour_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[1].split(":")[0]);
    int min_sys = Integer.parseInt(s[1].split(":")[1]);

    System.out.println("year_sys  => " + year_sys);
    System.out.println("month_sys  => " + month_sys);
    System.out.println("day_sys  => " + day_sys);

    System.out.println("hour_sys  => " + hour_sys);
    System.out.println("min_sys  => " + min_sys);
```

Answer (score 11):

You can simply use the following code:

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm"); // Format time
 String time = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

 DateFormat df1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd"); // Format date
 String date = df1.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Answer (score 10):

#### Current time and date in Android with the format

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("Current dateTime => " + c.getTime());
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
String formattedDate = df.format(c.getTime());
System.out.println("Format dateTime => " + formattedDate);
```

#### Output

```
I/System.out: Current dateTime => Wed Feb 26 02:58:17 GMT+05:30 2020
I/System.out: Format dateTime => 26-02-2020 02:58:17 AM
```

Answer (score 9):

For a customized time and date format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ",Locale.ENGLISH);
String cDateTime = dateFormat.format(new Date());
```

The output is in this format:

2015-06-18T10:15:56-05:00

Comment: The Date class [was deprecated in 1997](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--).

Answer (score 8):

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

Try this works for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

You can obtain the date by using:

```
Time t = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
t.setToNow();
String date = t.format("%Y/%m/%d");
```

This will give you a result in a nice form, as in this example: "2014/02/09".

Comment: The parameterless constructor `Time t = new Time();` will use the default timezone.  In my experience, default == current.

Answer (score 7):

Well, I had problems with some answers by the API, so I fused this code:

```
Time t = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
t.setToNow();
String date1 = t.format("%Y/%m/%d");

Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa", Locale.ENGLISH);
String var = dateFormat.format(date);
String horafecha = var+ " - " + date1;

tvTime.setText(horafecha);
```

Output:

```
03:25 PM - 2017/10/03
```

Answer (score 7):

Java

```
Long date=System.currentTimeMillis();
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat =new SimpleDateFormat("dd / MMMM / yyyy - HH:mm", Locale.getDefault());
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
```

Kotlin

date if milliseconds and 13 digits(hex to date)

```
val date=System.currentTimeMillis() //here the date comes in 13 digits
val dtlong = Date(date)
val sdfdate = SimpleDateFormat(pattern, Locale.getDefault()).format(dtlong)
```

Date Formatter

```
"dd / MMMM / yyyy - HH:mm" -> 29 / April / 2022 - 12:03 
"dd / MM / yyyy" -> 29 / 03 / 2022
"dd / MMM / yyyy" -> 29 / Mar / 2022 (shortens the month) 
"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss" -> Wed, 4 Jul 2022 12:08:56
```

Comment: Consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. Use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) in order to use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is so much nicer to work with.

Answer (score 6):

```
Date todayDate = new Date();
todayDate.getDay();
todayDate.getHours();
todayDate.getMinutes();
todayDate.getMonth();
todayDate.getTime();
```

Comment: That [seems to work](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) - *"Allocates a Date object and initializes it so that it represents the time at which it was allocated, measured to the nearest millisecond."*. But why wasn't it in the previous 16 answers, over more than 2 years? It seems too easy. Does it actually work on Android? Did it become available in a later version of Android?

Comment: [Another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-android/28315782#28315782) says *"The Date class is* ***deprecated*** *now."*. [A comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-android#comment6068406_5369725) says *"You should use Calendar or GregorianCalendar. The Date class is* ***deprecated."***.

Comment: The documentation for [getDate](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--), [getHours](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getHours--), etc. says ***"Deprecated."***. E.g., *"As of JDK version 1.1, replaced by Calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)."*. JDK version 1.1 was released in ***February 1997***(!!!) - deprecated for 16 years when this answer was posted.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the Calender class according to the new API. The *Date* class is deprecated now.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

String date = "" + cal.get(Calendar.DATE) + "-" + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "-" + cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

String time = "" + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) + ":" + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Comment: Yes, the Date class [was deprecated in 1997](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--).

Answer (score 5):

Try This

```
String mytime = (DateFormat.format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", new java.util.Date()).toString());
```

Comment: This is perfect one liner and elegant solution. That's all what is needed, not unnecessarily long solutions like in other answers.

Comment: The java.util.Date class [was deprecated in 1997](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--).

Answer (score 5):

The below method will return the current date and time in a String, Use a different time zone according to your actual time zone. I've used GMT.

```
public static String GetToday(){
    Date presentTime_Date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    return dateFormat.format(presentTime_Date);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this to get the current date and time in an easy way:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Try to use the below code:

```
 Date date = new Date();
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormatWithZone = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",Locale.getDefault());  
 String currentDate = dateFormatWithZone.format(date);
```

Answer (score 4):

For a 12-hour clock with suffix "AM" or "PM":

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("KK:mm:ss a, dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
String currentDateAndTime = df.format(new Date());
```

For a 24-hour clock with suffix "AM" or "PM":

```
 DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a, dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
 String currentDateAndTime = df.format(new Date());
```

To remove the suffix, just remove "a" written with the time format.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code. It displays the current date and time.

```
 Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
 SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa",
                         Locale.ENGLISH);
 String var = dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: Are you sure? The Date class [was deprecated in 1997](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getDay--).

Answer (score 3):

```
    //currentTimeMillis is System.currentTimeMillis()

    long totalSeconds = currentTimeMillis / 1000;
    int currentSecond = (int)totalSeconds % 60;

    long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
    int currentMinute = (int)totalMinutes % 60;

    long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
    int currentHour = (int)totalHours % 12;

    TextView tvTime = findViewById(R.id.tvTime);
    tvTime.setText((currentHour + OR - TIME YOU ARE FROM GMT) + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);
```

Comment: How does that get the current time and date?

Comment: edited the code..hadn't explained what currentTimeMillis is

Answer (score 2):

```
String DataString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

To get the short date formatted String in the localised format of the unit.

I can't understand why so many answers use hardcoded date and time formats when the OS/Java supplies correct localisation of date and time. Isn't it better always to use the formats of the device than of the programmer?

It also supplies the reading of dates in localised formats:

```
    DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = format.parse(DateString);
    }
    catch(ParseException e) {
    }
```

Then it is up to the user setting the format to show the dates and time and not you. Regardless of languages, etc., there are different formats in different countries with the same language.

Answer (score 2):

Here are a few ways to get time and date:

```
public static void getCurrentTimeUsingDate() {
    Date date = new Date();
    String strDateFormat = "hh:mm:ss a";
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat);
    String formattedDate= dateFormat.format(date);
    Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Time using Calender**

```
public static void getCurrentTimeUsingCalendar() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date date=cal.getTime();
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedDate=dateFormat.format(date);
    Toast.makeText(this, formattedDate, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Local time and date**

```
public static void getCurrentTime(){
    System.out.println("-----Current time of your time zone-----");
    LocalTime time = LocalTime.now();
    Toast.makeText(this, time, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Zone wise Time**

```
public static void getCurrentTimeWithTimeZone(){
    Toast.makeText(this, "Current time of a different time zone using LocalTime", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of("America/Los_Angeles");
    LocalTime localTime=LocalTime.now(zoneId);
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
    String formattedTime=localTime.format(formatter);
    Toast.makeText(this,formattedTime , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

**Easy way to get the current time and date**

```
import java.util.Calendar

Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
```

Answer (score 2):

### Kotlin

Here are various ways in to get the current date time in Kotlin.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println(System.currentTimeMillis()) // Current milliseconds

    val date = Calendar.getInstance().time // Current date object
    val date1 = Date(System.currentTimeMillis())

    println(date.toString())
    println(date1.toString())

    val now = Time(System.currentTimeMillis()) // Current time object
    println(now.toString())

    val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy:MM:dd h:mm a", Locale.getDefault())
    println(sdf.format(Date())) // Format current date

    println(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(System.currentTimeMillis())) // using getDateTimeInstance()

    println(LocalDateTime.now().toString()) // Java 8

    println(ZonedDateTime.now().toString()) // Java 8
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the **time & date** separately from Calendar.

```
// You can pass time zone and Local to getInstance() as parameter

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

int currentHour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
int currentMinute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
int second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND);
int date = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
int month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a *ISO8601Utils* utilities class in the *com.google.gson.internal.bind.util* package, so if you [Gson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gson) in your app you can use this.

It supports milliseconds and time zones, so it's a pretty good option right out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your local time with GMT time from this function

```
public String getCurrentDate() {
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd hh:mm a zzz");
    Date date = new Date();
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+6:00"));
    return sdf.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the current date and time using this code:

```
val current_data_time= SimpleDateFormat("MMMMddyyyyHHmm", Locale.getDefault())
val currentDateandTime: String = current_data_time.format(Date())
```

If you use MMMM: Then month name shows e.g. "March"

If you use MM: Then number shows e.g. "3"

*dd* for day and *yyyy* for year

If you want only the last two digits then *yy*.

If you change month and year first and last then need to change MMMM and dd and yyyy left and right, e.g., *12/3/2021 12:12* dd/MM/YYYY HH:mm

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin, you can **get current time** data using Calendar.

```
val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
```

This will give this output, `Thu Apr 06 17:38:57 GMT+05:30 2023`

Get current time hour, minute and second value like this.

```
val hour = calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)
val minute = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE)
val second = calendar.get(Calendar.SECOND)
val currentTime = "$hour:$minute:$second"
```

Output of currentTime will be this `17:38:57`.

Answer (score 0):

we can get time by Date() also