# Write Date and Time On video Recording Android

Tags: android

I want Date and time on video recording screen.When i start Recording video then get date and time and save into the storage .When play the video it will show on screen. I am facing problem for showing date time on video frame . if anyone have an idea for the same please help me .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41605535/how-to-showing-current-time-on-recorded-video-android

Comment: or you can follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23735464/how-to-embed-text-while-recording-video-in-android