# How can I show today's date in an android activity?

Tags: android, date

I am currently working on my project for my professional course. I am implementing a digital diary. 
I would be having a diary page (a multiline textbox maybe) And a TextView on top to show the current DATE (without time).  How do I show a NON-editabale textbox with today's date shown in it.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the current date and time use the below Links and iin order make it non editable in XML file make editable = false also focusable = false.

[LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date)

[LINK2](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date.html)

Answer (score 0):

its simple

```
        Date dt = new Date();
        int date = dt.getDate();
        int month = dt.getMonth()+1;
        int year = dt.getYear();
        year += 1900;
        int day = dt.getDay();
        String[] days = { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","WednesDay", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saterday" };
        String curDate = date + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + days[day];
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code :

```
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

It 'll print :
Feb 5, 2013, 12:35:46PM