# Date formatting based on user locale on android

Tags: android, internationalization, date-format

I want to display a date of birth based on the user locale. In my application, one of my fields is the date of birth, which is currently in the format `dd/mm/yyyy`. So if the user changes his locale, the date format should also change accordingly. Any pointers or code samples would really help me to overcome the problem.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5369682/1015595

Answer (score 101, accepted):

You can use the [DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html) class that formats a date according to the user locale.

Example:

```
String dateOfBirth = "26/02/1974";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
Date date = null;
try {
    date = sdf.parse(dateOfBirth);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    // handle exception here !
}
java.text.DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
String s = dateFormat.format(date);
```

You can use the different methods `getLongDateFormat`, `getMediumDateFormat` depending on the level of verbosity you would like to have.

Comment: "DateFormat dateFormat" should really be written "java.text.DateFormat dateFormat". There are different versions of DateFormat from various libraries.

Comment: Looking at the source code, `android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context)` simply returns `java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(java.text.DateFormat.SHORT)`. In fact, the `context` argument is not even used. I think I prefer to just use `java.text.DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT)` directly.

Comment: I don't have input date in string type, I have Date as input

Answer (score 54):

While the accepted answer was correct when the question was asked, it has later become outdated. I am contributing the modern answer.

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.SHORT);
    
    LocalDate dateOfBirth = LocalDate.of(1991, Month.OCTOBER, 13);
    String formattedDob = dateOfBirth.format(dateFormatter);
    System.out.println("Born: " + formattedDob);
```

It gives different output depending on the locale setting of the JVM (usually taking from the device). For example:

- Canadian French: `Born: 91-10-13`
- Chinese: `Born: 1991/10/13`
- German: `Born: 13.10.91`
- Italian: `Born: 13/10/91`

If you want a longer format, you may specify a different format style. Example outputs in US English locale:

- `FormatStyle.SHORT`: `Born: 10/13/91`
- `FormatStyle.MEDIUM`: `Born: Oct 13, 1991`
- `FormatStyle.LONG`: `Born: October 13, 1991`
- `FormatStyle.FULL`: `Born: Thursday, October 13, 1991`

### Question: Can I use java.time on Android?

> DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate requires Api O minimum.

Yes, java.time works nicely on older and newer Android devices. No, it does not require API level 26 or Oreo even though a message in your Android Studio might have you think that. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Question: Can I also accept user input in the user’s local format?

Yes, you can. The formatter can also be used for parsing a string from the user into a `LocalDate`:

```
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(userInputString, dateFormatter);
```

I suggest that you first format an example date and show it to the user so that s/he can see which format your program expects for his/her locale. As example date take a date with day of month greater than 12 and year greater than 31 so that the order of day, month and year can be seen from the example (for longer formats the year doesn’t matter since it will be four digits).

Parsing will throw a `DateTimeParseException` if the user entered the date in an incorrect format or a non-valid date. Catch it and allow the user to try again.

### Question: Can I do likewise with a time of day? A date and time?

Yes. For formatting a time of day according to a user’s locale, get a formatter from `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime`. For both date and time together use one of the overloaded versions of `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime`.

### Avoid the DateFormat, SImpleDateFormat and Date classes

I recommend you don’t use `DateFormat`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first two in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDate`, `DateTimeFormatter` and other classes from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate requires Api O minimum.

Comment: @PrajwalWaingankar Thanks for your comment. No it does not. I have edited the section *Question: Can I use java.time on Android?* and tried to make this a bit clearer.

Answer (score 22):

As simple as

For date + time:

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.DEFAULT, DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

For just date:

```
DateFormat format = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, Locale.getDefault());
```

Comment: Just to correct the copy paste error: For the date without time, call getDateInstance (not getDateTimeInstance)

Answer (score 16):

Android api provide easy way to display localized date format. 
The following code works.

```
public class FileDateUtil {
    public static String getModifiedDate(long modified) {
        return getModifiedDate(Locale.getDefault(), modified);
    }

    public static String getModifiedDate(Locale locale, long modified) {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = null;

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(getDateFormat(locale));
        } else {
            dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        }

        return dateFormat.format(new Date(modified));
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2)
    public static String getDateFormat(Locale locale) {
        return DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(locale, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
    }
}
```

You can check following code.

```
String koreaData = FileDateUtil.getModifiedDate(Locale.KOREA, System.currentTimeMillis());
String franceData = FileDateUtil.getModifiedDate(Locale.FRENCH, System.currentTimeMillis());
String defaultData = FileDateUtil.getModifiedDate(Locale.getDefault(), System.currentTimeMillis());

String result = "Korea : " + koreaData + System.getProperty("line.separator");
result += "France : " + franceData + System.getProperty("line.separator");
result += "Default : " + defaultData + System.getProperty("line.separator"); 
tv.setText(result);
```

Comment: woah, DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern is a life saver. I've wasted a few days trying to set up the right patterns using DateTimeFormatter from Java SDK with no success only to now find out DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern does everything I wanted

Comment: This still uses the outdated and somewhat buggy time.util and SimpleDateFormat. Should change to java.time.

Answer (score 14):

To change the date format according to the locale, the following code worked to me:

```
    String dateOfBirth = "26/02/1974";
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = sdf.parse(dateOfBirth);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // handle exception here !
    }

    String myString = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);
```

Then when you change the locale, the date format will change based on it.
For more information about the dates patterns:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/dateFormat.html

Answer (score 0):

To get the date format pattern you can do :

```
Format dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(getApplicationContext());
String pattern = ((SimpleDateFormat) dateFormat).toLocalizedPattern();
```

After that, you can format your input as per the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

**The simple way to do it:**

```
String AR_Format = "dd-mm-yyyy";
String EN_Format = "mm-dd-yyyy";

String getFomattedDateByLocale(Date date, String locale) {
    return new SimpleDateFormat(strDateFormat, new Locale(locale)).format(date);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
txtArabicDate.setText(getFomattedDateByLocale(new Date(), AR_Format));
txtEnglishDate.setText(getFomattedDateByLocale(new Date(), EN_Format));
```

Don't forget to replace `new Date()` by your own date variable.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

My way, with example: UTC iso format String to android User.

```
    //string UTC instant to localDateTime
    String example = "2022-01-27T13:04:23.891374801Z"
    Instant instant = Instant.parse(example);
    TimeZone timeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, timeZone.toZoneId());

    //localDateTime to device culture string output
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate(FormatStyle.LONG);
    String strDate = localDateTime.toLocalDate().format(dateFormatter);
    DateTimeFormatter timeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedTime(FormatStyle.MEDIUM);
    String strTime = localDateTime.toLocalTime().format(timeFormatter);

    //strings to views
    txtDate.setText(strDate);
    txtTime.setText(strTime);
```