# How to display date format according to locale?

Tags: android, date, locale

I want to display a hint how a date should be entered.
For Germany it might look like

"Enter date in this format: dd.mm.yyy"

For the US

"Enter date in this format: mm/dd/yyyy"

I understand that with

```
DateFormat dateFormat = android.text.format.DateFormat.getDateFormat(context);
```

I can convert a date into a format matching the user's locale.
But how would I get the day/month/year string for the hint?

And of course I would want the similar thing with a hint for time, too.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String hintText = new SimpleDateFormat().toPattern(); // dd/MM/y HH:mm
```

I know you were asking for just the date, but this was as close as I can get.
The internal rule is `localeData.getDateFormat(SHORT) + " " + localeData.getTimeFormat(SHORT)` so I guess as long as there is not a locale that has a date format with spaces on it, you can just split the string on a space

Comment: Yes works. I have to see, what to do with potentially more than on blank in the result string. Thank you.

Comment: I believe samgak solution is better than my own. But as you have stated in the comments, It's API 18+

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [getBestDateTimePattern](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getBestDateTimePattern(java.util.Locale,%20java.lang.String)) method of DateFormat:

```
String datePattern = DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), "ddMMyyyy");
String timePattern = DateFormat.getBestDateTimePattern(Locale.getDefault(), "HHmmss");
```

note: assumes 24-hour format for the time. You might want to convert to all upper or lower case before presentation to the user.

Comment: Works like a charm, unfortunately only from API level 18 (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html#getBestDateTimePattern(java.util.Locale, java.lang.String)) onwards. Seems I need to go with the solution @WORMSS suggested

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                            int month = cal.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                            int day = cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                            int hour = cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                            int minute = cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                            int second = cal.get(Calendar.SECOND);

Calendar now = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day, hour, minute, second);

long time = now.getTimeInMillis();
Date date = new Date(time);

String timeSet = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.SHORT, DateFormat.SHORT).format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier to get you date with a date picker: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html#DatePicker

If not, then take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11093572/3965178