# Angular - Get the format, as string, used to display dates according to locale

Tags: angular, angular-date-format

How can I get the format, as a string, used by Angular to display dates ? I use the `date` pipe after setting `LOCALE_ID` in my `app.module`.

Now I'd like to retrieve the "dd/mm/yyyy" string, to put in my input placeholders.

Basically, what's described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143083/how-to-display-date-format-according-to-locale) but for Angular.

Thanks

[edit]

To make it more explicit, I'm not looking for a way to format dates, that's already done (with the native `date` pipe). I want the string that represents the format being used by this pipe.

Because I'd like my datepicker placeholder to be like

"Date (format: XXXXXX)"

and I want the "XXXXXX" part to be correct (i.e. "jj/mm/aaaa" for french, "mm/dd/yyyy" for english)

Comment: I am not clear what you mean but [moment](https://momentjs.com/) might help you.

Comment: I've edited my post. I hope there is an Angular native way of doing this

Comment: you are never gonna get a translated string like "jj/mm/aaaa", best you can possibly get is "dd/mm/yyyy" for your french example. The "english" format string is in the LDML data (@angular/common/locales), so in theory you should be able to extract that information somehow, but what use is it in english? Personally I would just add the placeholder as a string and include it in my translation files.

Comment: I want a more generic way of getting this string because we will handle many languages, and we don't know their format, we'll trust Angular on that point (I'm ok with having 'dd/mm/yyyy' for french)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I hope that in the meantime you've come across getLocaleDateFormat() and getLocaleTimeFormat(). (Angular 6)

```
import { getLocaleDateFormat, FormatWidth } from '@angular/common';
export class Foobar {
  constructor( @Inject( LOCALE_ID ) private locale: string ) { }

  private getDateFormat() {
    return getLocaleDateFormat( this.locale, FormatWidth.Short );
  }
}
```

Comment: For the locale `fr-FR`, you'll get exactly `dd/MM/y`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to declaratively format a date within your template:

```
{{ today | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy' }}
```

If you want to imperatively get the formatted date within code:

```
import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
// in your component class
var date = new DatePipe().transform(today, 'dd/MM/yyyy')
```