# Android: Display time in correct format when i have hour and minutes as int

Tags: android, datetimepicker, timepicker

i get the hour and minutes out of a TimePickerDialog:

```
public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hour, int minute) {
    // Do something with the time chosen by the user
}
```

I want to display this time somewhere else. My approach would be to check the user settings for 12h or 24h format with

```
DateFormat.is24HourFormat()
```

and then build the time text manually.

My question: Is there a better way to do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use SimpleDateFormat like this for 24 hours:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss);
```

or change `HH` to `hh` to get 12 hours format:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss);
```

then just use:

```
dateFormat.format(yourDate);
```

which you can get using calendar:

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat;
if (DateFormat.is24HourFormat()) {
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss);
} else {
    dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss);
}
Calendar c = new Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.HOUR, yourIntHour); // Or HOUR_OF_DAY
c.set(Calendar.MINUTE, yourIntMinute);
Date d = c.getTime();
String dateResult = dateFormat.format(d);
```

You can use `HOUR_OF_DAY` instead of `HOUR`:
(soruce: javadoc)

> public static final int HOUR
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the morning or
>   afternoon. HOUR is used for the 12-hour clock (0 - 11). Noon and
>   midnight are represented by 0, not by 12. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM the
>   HOUR is 10.
>
> public static final int HOUR_OF_DAY
>
> Field number for get and set indicating the hour of the day.
>   HOUR_OF_DAY is used for the 24-hour clock. E.g., at 10:04:15.250 PM
>   the HOUR_OF_DAY is 22.

Comment: Thank you, but i always have to make that manual check for DateFormat.is24HourFormat() ? So there is no way to save the result of the timePicker in a way that it displays the correct format automatically when i use it?

Comment: This may be an answer for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093182/date-formatting-based-on-user-locale-on-android I personally like the most the last answer

Answer (score 0):

You can force the timepicker to be 12 hours picker using `timePicker.setIs24HourView(boolean)`:

```
timePicker.setIs24HourView(DateFormat.is24HourFormat(getContext()));
```

Comment: I mean that you have not to handle the time text manually. Change to format of timepicker and get the desired format of time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But this way i force the 12 format upon every user, right? Since i am from germany myself i want to give the possibilty to user 24 hour format.