# Kotlin convert yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss to human readable string

Tags: date, datetime, kotlin

Hello everyone i am just learning android and i got this case when i have the data with content of 
`2021-05-16T05:02:26Z` 
which have this format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss` 
How can i convert it to `Sunday-May-2021 05:02` ? 
I've tried googling and exploring the web but most of them only convert yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss to dd-mm-yyyy and any other format, haven't found one that convert it to human readable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don’t you want to have the day of the month in the format (16 in the example)? And don’t you want the time converted to the user’s time zone? The time in your string is in UTC (05:02 in the example).

Comment: Related, only based on Java instead of Kotlin: [Date formatting based on user locale on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093182/date-formatting-based-on-user-locale-on-android).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) patterns. In your case it would look like this:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val zonedTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2021-05-16T05:02:26Z")
val formatted : String = zonedTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE-MMMM-u HH:mm"))
```