# How to get current date time in milliseconds in android

Tags: android

i am trying to save my file with name as  current date and time in milliseconds. and while reading file i want to read latest one.Here is the code

```
 Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

  long offset = rightNow.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) +  rightNow.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

  String sinceMidnight = Long.toString((rightNow.getTimeInMillis() + offset) %  (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));

  return sinceMidnight+"_"+Filename;
```

Comment: good. But what is problem?

Comment: @PankajKumar how to read the latest one

Comment: @Supreet- System.currentTimeMillis(); -Returns the current system time in milliseconds

Comment: @Pratik this shows error

Comment: Try the soln. that i have mentioned. Im not too sure on why you would need the offset. If you are using this value to retrieve the date then setTime (your file name) would anyway set with the same timestamp value.

Comment: @Supreet System.currentTimeMillis(); what error happened when you use this?

Comment: @edwin thanks dude its allmost done

Comment: thanks to all guys for your effort

Answer (score 356):

I think leverage this functionality using Java

```
long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
```

this will return current time in milliseconds mode . this will surely work

```
long time= System.currentTimeMillis();
android.util.Log.i("Time Class ", " Time value in millisecinds "+time);
```

Here is my logcat using the above function

```
05-13 14:38:03.149: INFO/Time Class(301): Time value in millisecinds 1368436083157
```

If you got any doubt with millisecond value .Check [Here](http://www.fileformat.info/tip/java/date2millis.htm)

**EDIT** : Time Zone I used to demo the code IST(+05:30) ,So if you check `milliseconds` that mentioned in log **to match with time in log** you might get a different value based your system timezone

**EDIT**: This is easy approach .but if you need time zone or any other details I think this won't be enough
[Also See this approach using android api support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369713)

Comment: This is the most unreliable way to get the current time considering that different systems will return a different value. The documentation is quite explicit about it

Comment: @Leo hope you have read my edits , which is same point you mentioned.

Answer (score 25):

The problem is that `System. currentTimeMillis();` returns the number of milliseconds from 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z, but `new Date()` gives the current local time. Adding the **ZONE_OFFSET and DST_OFFSET** from the Calendar class gives you the time in UTC.

```
Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

// offset to add since we're not UTC

long offset = rightNow.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) +
    rightNow.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);

long sinceMidnight = (rightNow.getTimeInMillis() + offset) %
    (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

System.out.println(sinceMidnight + " milliseconds since midnight");
```

Comment: how does this answer differ from OP?

Comment: @sunil kumar rightNow.getTimeInMillis() will return you local time in Milli Seconds so I believe offset will be subtracted from rightNow.getTimeInMillis() else this will not work for time zones with (GMT+N). 
    long sinceMidnight = (rightNow.getTimeInMillis() + offset) %
    (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
  Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
  int mseconds = c.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND)
```

an alternative would be

```
 Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();

 long offset = rightNow.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET) +
        rightNow.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);
 long sinceMid = (rightNow.getTimeInMils() + offset) %
       (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

  System.out.println(sinceMid + " milliseconds since midnight");
```

Comment: see this reference it may help you http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SystemClock.html#setCurrentTimeMillis%28long%29

Answer (score -1):

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(new Date());
int mSec = calendar.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND);
```