# Get System time in Milliseconds in android

Tags: java, android, time

Want to get time in milliseconds in android **Ex 19:57:21:522**.How do i do this?Could not find any straight forward API's to do so.

Comment: Check this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16516888/how-to-get-current-date-time-in-milliseconds-in-android

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8826270/how-to-convert-hhmmss-sss-to-milliseconds

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android get current time and date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try SimpleDateFormat

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Use a pattern with a capital S

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
```

Comment: I suggest using Java doc from Java 6 or 7.

Comment: SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS", Locale.US); specifies the Locale