# android - why is current time less than a back date time in Calendar

Tags: java, android, android-calendar

Date time set in calendar is '2016-6-18 13:54:00 ' and current date time is '2016-6-18 14:45:00' i.e. 2016-6-18 2:45 PM. In the calendar I set the `MONTH` value to be 5 as month is zero-based there. This is in android :

```
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2016);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, 5);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DATE, 18);
        calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,13);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,54);
        calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);

        long alarmTime =calendar.getTimeInMillis();
        alarmTime = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(alarmTime);        

        long timeMillis = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long currentTimeSeconds =TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(timeMillis);

        if (alarmTime > currentTimeSeconds) {

           Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is set", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }else{

          Toast.makeText(context, "Alarm is not set",  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             }
```

But the result shows the toast "Alarm is set" whereas I expected the otherwise i.e. "Alarm is not set".

What is going on here ?

**EDIT:**  To my surprise, the [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/) emulator shows 'Alarm is set' while the real device shows 'Alarm is not set'.  Why is this difference ?

Comment: Code is perfect, and it is working in my local environment perfectly. Kindly recompile and run again.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath, do you find 'Alarm not set', really ?

Comment: @ClementAmarnath, edited OP.

Comment: Please Can you post allarmTime value and currentTimeSeconds value just before "if" instr in both emulator and real device?

Answer (score 0):

Use Calendar.getIstance().getTimeInMillis()

to compare with the first time Calendar time. Look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16516978

in general is a good practice compare   *data* or *date* generated by the same class.

Comment: didn't I do that ?

Comment: No you did not. You are using System.currentTimeMillis() instead of calendar.getIstance().getTimeInMillisec()

Comment: Where is `getTimeInMillisec` documented in developer.android.com?

Comment: I mean getTimeInMillis()

Comment: Changet System.currentTimeMillis() to Calendar.getIstance().getTimeInMillis()

Comment: Why should that make any difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a time zone issue.

Note that [`Calendar.getInstance()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28%29) creates a `Calendar` object using the default timezone (i.e. the time zone that's configured in the device settings).

So if your Genymotion emulator is set to UTC the created `Calendar` object represents `2016-06-18 13:54:00 UTC` which is `2016-06-18 14:54:00 GMT+1`

If your device is in GTM+1, the created `Calendar` object represents `2016-06-18 13:54:00 GMT+1`.

To fix this make sure you call [`Calendar.getInstance(ZimeTone)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html#getInstance%28java.util.TimeZone%29) passing the correct time zone that's associated with your alarm.