# OnBackPressed() on a time

Tags: android

I want to disable back  button. I know that I can do it via onBackPressed(). But I want disable thi button for a while time (20 second). Help me please, how I do it?

Comment: If you know the method that you need to override, what is the question then?? just check for a timer or something

Answer (score 1):

In onCreate catch starting time and save it.
Then inside onBackPressed check current time against that time.

here is how you can get time
[Get current time and date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date)

here is how onBackPressed would look like more less

```
if((startTime - currentTime) < 20min)
   return;
else
   super.onBackPressed()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                super.onbackpressed();
        }
   }, 20000); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just use

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

just remover super method like above