# How to get time on Android phone programmatically?

Tags: java, android

I am using this Java method here to get the current time:

```
final Date d = new Date();
d.getTime();

1390283202624
```

What I am getting a numeric figure of datatype long. What I need is the exact time in the format **hh:mm:ss**. And in the end I also have to perform arithmetic on the figure obtained.

Any clue? Also is this a reliable way of obtaining time on Android phone because I am getting a constant value here?

Comment: read about `SimpleDateFormat`

Comment: Use the constants in the Calendar class: `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
    int hour = instance.get(Calendar.HOUR);
    int minute = instance.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    int second = instance.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Comment: I am getting a constant value on my emulator each time I click the button to execute this code. Why?

Answer (score 4):

```
Date d = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String formattedDate = sdf.format(d);
System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
String time=sdf.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Calendar](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) class.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/android-get-current-time-and-date). Calendar class contain all desired information.