# Android: Adding date to Database?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a column in my database for date. Currently I am using a miliseconds value as a substitute, however I want to be able to add the actual date and time to it.

I have seen that the following can be used from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android) but im unsure how to implement it in my current code? (shown below):

```
Time now = new Time();
now.setToNow();
```

Also, do I need to change my DatabaseHelper class, to change that column from a Long to a different value?

Current code for adding to the database:

```
DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        // Inserting Contacts
        Log.d("Insert: ", "Inserting ..");

        db.addScore(new Score(UserName.getUserName(), averageMedLevel, System
                .currentTimeMillis()));


        // Reading all contacts
        Log.d("Reading: ", "Reading all contacts..");
        List<Score> scores = db.getAllScores();

        for (Score s : scores) {
            String log = "Name: " + s.getName() + " Meditation: "
                    + s.getMeditation() + "Date: " + s.getDate();
            // Writing Contacts to log
            Log.d("Details: ", log);
        }


    }
```

Database helper class:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    // Database Version
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    // Database Name
    private final static String DATABASE_NAME = "MeditationDatabase";

    // Contacts table name
    private static final String TABLE_SCORE = "scores";

    // Contacts Table Columns names
    private static final String COL_NAME = "name";
    private static final String COL_MED = "meditation";
    private static final String COL_DATE = "date";

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param context
     */
    public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * Method that creates the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // NOTE: may need to alter the below to take out everything after
        // INTEGER
        String CREATE_TABLE_SCORE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + "("
                + COL_NAME + " STRING PRIMARY KEY," + COL_MED + " INTEGER,"
                + COL_DATE + " LONG" + ")";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_SCORE);

    }

    /**
     * Method that upgrades the database
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE);

        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);

    }

    /**
     * All CRUD operations
     */
    // Adding new score details (Name, score, date)
    void addScore(Score score) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        // ContentValues- holds the values.
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(COL_NAME, score.getName());
        values.put(COL_MED, score.getMeditation());
        values.put(COL_DATE, score.getDate());

        // Inserting Row (i.e. the values that were entered from above
        db.insert(TABLE_SCORE, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection

    }

    /**
     * Method will return a single Name and score
     * 
     * @param id
     * @return
     */
    // Getting single contact
    Score getScore(String name) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

        Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_SCORE, new String[] { COL_NAME,
                COL_MED, COL_DATE }, COL_NAME + "=?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(name) }, null, null, null, null);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.moveToFirst();

        Score score = new Score(cursor.getString(0), Integer.parseInt(cursor
                .getString(1)), cursor.getLong(2));
        // return contact
        return score;
    }

    /**
     * Method will return a list of all the scores
     * 
     * @return
     */
    // Getting All scores
    public List<Score> getAllScores() {
        List<Score> scoreList = new ArrayList<Score>();
        // Select All Query
        String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_SCORE;

        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

        // looping through all rows and adding to list
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Score score = new Score();
                score.setName(cursor.getString(0));
                score.setMeditation(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(1)));
                score.setDate(cursor.getLong(2));
                // Adding contact to list
                scoreList.add(score);
            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }

        // return contact list
        return scoreList;
    }

}
```

Comment: AFAIK, the preferred solution here is to store the date in milliseconds since some fixed date and convert it to something more readable at runtime.

Comment: Yeah, however I am unsure how to do so>

Comment: `Currently I am using a miliseconds`. what else is a date ?

Comment: A date as in The time, day, week, month, year etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go through the following link , this will help you,

http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#affinity

Whatever you insert , Sqlite type affinity will take care of it. If your data type is mismatching or anything this will become a text value in your table while inserting.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
            long time= c.getTimeInMillis();` 

to get current time in milliseconds then u can put this in to ContentValue to insert it in Database

```
values.put(COL_DATE, time);
```

Comment: Yes but this doesnt actually give a date?