# How to get current time of action in Android?

Tags: android, time

How can I get the time an action was performed in the users preset format (24/12Hr)? I'm trying to set a textview with the time an onClick was performed.

EDIT: I've tried

```
Time currentTime = new Time();
currentTime.setToNow();
```

However, instead of XX:XX/X:XX I get a bunch of unneeded text.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get current time and date on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android)

Answer (score 1):

The question have been asked already, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9464874/657487).
So, to put current date-time in `TextView` use the following code:

```
time.setText(DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

If You need only time (without date), then it should look the following:

```
time.setText(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()))
```

Also, checkout [getTimeInstance(int style)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DateFormat.html#getTimeInstance%28int%29) which allows to use different style of the format (e.g. long, short, medium).