# How to get the total number of minutes in the day so far?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, android-calendar

How do you get the total number of minutes in the day so far in Java (Android)? Is this possible?
For example, if it was 12:37am, I would want it to return int 37 (37 minutes so far that day). Or if it was 1:41am, I would want it to return int 101 (101 minutes so far that day), or if it 12:20pm, it would return int 740 (740 total minutes that day).

Comment: I would do math using the result of [`Calendar.get`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) for the various (hour, minute, second) fields on the time representing now. It is also possible to compute the difference between now and "the start of today", for which duplicate questions surely exist.

Comment: what problem you face on doing this? If you can get the current time, then all you need to do is just a simple math I guess

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox, wow I can't believe that never occurred to me.

Comment: @Jonjongot No, **you cannot just use simple math**. Daylight Saving Time means days can be 23, 24, or 25 hours long. For example, 03:00 could be 120 or 180 minutes. Besides DST, you need to account for other anomalies in various places. And you need time zone to know when a day starts (ex: Paris vs Montréal).  Use a good date-time library for such work. In Android, that means [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/). See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25738113/642706).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.now( z ) ;
long minutesIntoTheDay = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between( 
    zdt.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z ) ,
    zdt 
);
```

## Time Zone

The other answers are incorrect in that they fail to account for time zone. If you want minutes since start of day, which day? The day starting in Kolkata, Paris, or Montréal? A 23-hour, 24-hour, 25-hour, or some other length day?

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name). Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are not true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

## Using java.time

Get the current moment, [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html), for your desired/expected time zone by specifying a [`ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now( zoneId );
```

To get the number of minutes into the day, get the first moment of the day, and then calculated elapsed time.

```
ZonedDateTime startOfDay = now.toLocalDate().atStartOfDay( z );
```

Calculate elapsed time either as a `Duration` or use the `ChronoUnit` enum.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( startOfDay , now );
long minutesIntoTheDay = duration.toMinutes();
```

…or…

```
long minutesIntoTheDay = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between( startOfDay , now );
```

### Example: `Europe/Amsterdam`

Here is an example showing the DST cutover (“Spring forward”) [for the Netherlands](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/change/netherlands/amsterdam) in time zone [`Europe/Amsterdam`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Amsterdam) this year of 2017, on March 26 at 2 AM.

```
LocalDate march26 = LocalDate.of ( 2017, Month.MARCH, 26 );
LocalTime twoAm = LocalTime.of ( 2, 0 );
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of ( "Europe/Amsterdam" );
ZonedDateTime start = march26.atStartOfDay ( z );
ZonedDateTime stop = ZonedDateTime.of ( march26, twoAm, z );
long minutes = ChronoUnit.MINUTES.between ( start, stop );
Duration duration = Duration.between ( start, stop );
long durationAsMinutes = duration.toMinutes ( );
int minuteOfDay = stop.get ( ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println ( "start: " + start );
System.out.println ( "stop: " + stop );
System.out.println ( "minutes: " + minutes );
System.out.println ( "FYI: 4 * 60 = " + ( 4 * 60 ) + " | 3 * 60 = " + ( 3 * 60 ) + " | 2 * 60 = " + ( 2 * 60 ) );
System.out.println ( "duration.toString(): " + duration + " | durationAsMinutes: " + durationAsMinutes );
System.out.println ( "minuteOfDay: " + minuteOfDay );
```

You can see this [code run live at IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/8P0lcD).

> start: 2017-03-26T00:00+01:00[Europe/Amsterdam]
>
> stop: 2017-03-26T03:00+02:00[Europe/Amsterdam]
>
> minutes: 120
>
> FYI: 4 * 60 = 240 | 3 * 60 = 180 | 2 * 60 = 120
>
> duration.toString(): PT2H | durationAsMinutes: 120
>
> minuteOfDay: 180

Note in the output:

- The [offset-from-UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) changes by an hour, going from `+01:00` to `+02:00`.
- The time-of-day we requested was 2 AM, but there is no such time-of-day on that date. Two o’clock in the morning simply does not exist on that date as the clocks jumped ahead an hour. Of course, space-time did not bend nor warp. Only *two* hours of actual time elapsed between midnight and 3 AM, not three. The designers of the java.time classes chose to resolve the problem by adjusting the time-of-day value ahead to the valid time-of-day. Read the doc to be sure you understand and agree with such behavior.
- The result of `ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY` is not correct/precise because that feature accounts only for generic 24-hour days rather than actual anomalous dates such as this date with DST cutover. We see `180` minutes whereas only 120 minutes actually elapsed.

**CORRECTION:** This Answer formerly advised using [`ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoField.html#MINUTE_OF_DAY). That was poor advice as that feature uses generic 24-hour days. Anomalies such as Daylight Saving Time (DST) are ignored. So the results may not be precise/correct for particular dates in certain time zones. This behavior is clearly documented:

> ChronoField MINUTE_OF_DAY
>
> public static final ChronoField MINUTE_OF_DAY
>
> The minute-of-day.
>
> This counts the minute within the day, from 0 to (24 * 60) - 1. This field has the same meaning for all calendar systems.
>
> When parsing this field it behaves equivalent to the following: The value is validated in strict and smart mode but not in lenient mode. The value is split to form MINUTE_OF_HOUR and HOUR_OF_DAY fields.

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8) and [**SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9) and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: On the day daylight saving times starts (f.i. 2017/03/26 12:00 in Europe/Amsterdam), `MINUTE_OF_DAY` reports 720 (12*60), but the we just skipped 60 minutes from 1:59 to 3:00. So it should be 660. JodaTime does the same. On the other hand, `dstStartDayAtStartOfDay.until(dstStartDayAtNoon,ChronoUnit.MINUTES)` reports the correct 660 minutes (and with `HOURS` 11h). When DST end, the pattern repeats: `.until()` give 13h/780min from midnight until lunch time on 2017/10/29.
So far I could not find an explanation for the discrepancy between the two results.

Comment: @Ivin You are correct, my suggestion to use `ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_DAY` is ill-advised. That feature works only for generic 24-hour days, not for an anomalous date such as DST cutover. I revised this Answer to suggest other features instead.

Answer (score 16):

I actually used the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) class to figure this out.

Here is the code, with `currentMinuteOfDay` being the total number of minutes.

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hour = now.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        int minute = now.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        int currentMinuteOfDay = ((hour * 60) + minute);
```

Answer (score 5):

I'm with stupid,

Here's the pseudo algorithm:

```
  1. Get the current time in hours and minutes
  2. Multiple hours * 60 + minutes, and this is your answer!
```

I would recommend using the Date class:

```
 Date date = new Date();
```

You can read up more on the `Date` class [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-how-to-get-current-date-time-date-and-calender/).

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: AM/PM are artificial designators; all Calendar/Date objects use 24-hour clocks (but note odd access like HOUR vs HOUR_OF_DAY).

Comment: ahh, I see; I wasn't aware of that. Thank you for the new knowledge and clarification @user2864740! :0)

Comment: This answer ignores time zone. The java.util.Date class has no time zone, and represents only UTC. If you want the number of minutes since start of day, you have to do something else. The day starts at different times in Kolkata, Paris, and Montréal.

Answer (score 1):

Set your start time at midnight. Then when you want the total number of minutes that have passed just grab the current time. Then grab the whole number of both times, subtract `startTime_hour` from `currentTime_hour`.

Then grab the minutes component of the times, in your case only from `currentTime` minutes. Convert the minutes to decimal using this relation:

```
30mins/.50
```

Which is simply, 30 minutes = 0.50. In code it will look like this:

```
currentTime_mins_decimal = .50 * currentTime_mins / 30;
```

Now you want to add the result from the first subtraction to `currentTime_mins_decimal` and multiply the whole thing by 60.

Then convert from decimal to minutes by using the same relation: `30mins/.50` The benefit of changing was that if your start time is not midnight but something with minutes, let's say 12:55 when you do your arithmetic you won't get accurate results.

Comment: How do you get "the total number of minutes"? There is no benefit going that route and then changing.

Answer (score 1):

Based onn the answer to [Get current time and date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369753/2055998) post:

```
public int getTodayMinutesAsOfNow() {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
    return c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)*60 + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
}
```