# Kotlin: How to detect 'date change'?

Tags: kotlin

I will use `Timer()` to execute function by 5 minutes in Kotlin.

And when I execute function by 5m, if a day passed,I want count var to be 0.

So my idea was

1. declare two `vars`

   ```kotlin
   var todayDate = LocalDate.now() // 2019-09-23
   var todayCount:Int = 0
   ```
2. After that I will check this vars in 5 minutes by using `Timer()`

Then `todayDate` value differs from previous `todayDate`, then I can detect date change.

However, I don't know how to compare current `todayDate` and previous `todayDate`.

Any idea? or is there any other way to know day change?

Comment: Instead of tracking `todayDate` you could [use `java.time` to compute how many minutes have elapsed today](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25736410/how-to-get-the-total-number-of-minutes-in-the-day-so-far), and if it's under 5 minutes, then reset `todayCount`

Answer (score 0):

For your specific question about comparing dates you can use the `isEqual()` method on your `LocalDate` instance ([docs](https://howtodoinjava.com/java/date-time/compare-localdates/)). Something like the following would likely do what you want:

```kotlin
// initial state
var todayDate = LocalDate.now()
var todayCount = 0

// in each timer iteration:
val now = LocalDate.now()
if (!todayDate.isEqual(now)) {
  // it's a new day
  todayCount = 0
  todayDate = now
} else {
  // it's the same day
  ++todayCount
}
```

**However** if you're talking about Android and using its `Timer` class, you need to be aware that that runs on a background thread and you will need to persist your `todayDate` and `todayCount` values somewhere (which could be app preferences, your app DB, etc.).