# how to convert date and time to 12 hour format

Tags: android, string, datetime, android-datepicker

hello i have a date and time string in 24 hour format but i want it in 12 hour how i can do this my string is

```
String date_st="12 Nov, 2014 23:13"
```

i am doing this

```
 SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' 'MMM,' 'yyyy HH:mm aa");
```

but its not converting according to my need it shows 23:13 PM

i want to show in following format

```
String con_date= "12 Nov, 2014 11:13 PM"
```

how i can do this?

Comment: 'K' and 'h' return time in 12 hours format,'H' and 'k' return time in 24 hours format more check : http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: you mean i can write it like  SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' 'MMM,' 'yyyy KK:mm");

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need two formats: one to parse, and one to format. You need to parse from `String` to `Date` with one `DateFormat`, then format that `Date` into a `String` with the other format.

Currently, your single `SimpleDateFormat` is half way between - you've got `HH` which is 24-hour, but you've also got `aa` which is for am/pm. You want `HH` without the `aa` for input, and `hh` *with* the `aa` for output. (It's almost *never* appropriate to have both `HH` and `aa`.)

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("etc/UTC");
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm",
                                              Locale.US);
inputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm aa",
                                              Locale.US);
outputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);

Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
String output = outputFormat.format(date);
```

Note that I'm setting the locale to US so it can always parse "Nov", and the time zone to UTC so you don't need to worry about certain times being skipped or ambiguous.

Comment: @AhsanMalik: Do you mean the one where I wasn't setting the locale or time zone? If so, it will work *if* you're in the right locale and *if* the given date/time isn't ambiguous/skipped in the default time zone. I prefer to give answers which will work for all valid input though :) Of course, if your input actually uses the month names from the current locale, you shouldn't specify the locale... but in my experience, most of the time that you're parsing a text representation which includes a month name, it *is* in English even if the user isn't.

Comment: @JonSkeet: nice answer, well explained...no other answer required here...great...+1

Comment: `Note that I'm setting the locale to US so it can always parse "Nov", and the time zone to UTC so you don't need to worry about certain times being skipped or ambiguous.` Jon can you please explain this? Wouldn't the month will parse to Nov if i use chinese or lets say gb locale? and what's this times being skipped or ambigous?

Comment: @MuhammadBabar: It would work for the GB, but I doubt that it would work in a Chinese locale, as I doubt that the Chinese short name for November is "Nov". The part about times being skipped or ambiguous is due to time zones which skip over or repeat times due to daylight saving transitions.

Comment: @JonSkeet well that's a new thing for me. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

try with this answer this is shortest and best answer on stack.

```
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
     SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss aa");
     Datetime = sdf.format(c.getTime());
     System.out.println("============="+Datetime);
```

Result:-=========2015-11-20 05:52:25 PM

try with this link [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android/34328449#34328449)

Answer (score 2):

Try understand [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) Symbol and Meaning :

```
 Symbol       Meaning
   H      hour in day (0-23)
   K      hour in am/pm (0-11)
   h      hour in am/pm (1-12)
   k      hour in day (1-24)

SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' 'MMM,' 'yyyy KK:mm aa");
```

**OR**

```
SimpleDateFormat  dateformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' 'MMM,' 'yyyy hh:mm aa");
```

**Example:**

```
convertDateStringFormat("12 Nov, 2014 23:13","dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm","dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm aa")

public String convertDateStringFormat(String strDate, String fromFormat, String toFormat){
   try{
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
       sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
       SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat.trim());
       return dateFormat2.format(sdf.parse(strDate));
   }catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
       return "";
   }
 }
```