# I want to change 24 hours time format to 12 hours while selecting from seek bar

Tags: android, time-format

This is my code for time(to select a time)..This displays a time in 24 hour format...i need to change that in 12 hours...Where i need to add the code...What code i have to add...Please help me to find out the code

this is my code for time

```
seekBar_startTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                start_Time = String.valueOf(progresValue);
                textView_startTime.setText("Event Start Time :" + progresValue);
            }
        });

        seekBar_endTime.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {

                end_Time = String.valueOf(progresValue);
                textView_endTime.setText("Event End Time :" + progresValue);
            }
        });
```

Comment: change your seek bar value from 1-24 to 1-12 and add some widget for AM and PM

Comment: How to change the seek bar value

Comment: change in xml min and max

Comment: Thank you ...it shows 12 hours format...how to define am and pm in time

Comment: you can put `ToggleButon` or `RadioButton`  for selecting AM or PM

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
TimeZone utc = TimeZone.getTimeZone("etc/UTC");
DateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy HH:mm",
                                              Locale.US);
inputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);
DateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM, yyyy hh:mm aa",
                                              Locale.US);
outputFormat.setTimeZone(utc);

Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
String output = outputFormat.format(date);
```

visit here for more help [how to convert date and time to 12 hour format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26882714/how-to-convert-date-and-time-to-12-hour-format)

Answer (score 0):

If the `progresValue` variable is integer in the range of 1-24 representing the hour part of time...this would do:

```
final String time;
if(progressValue > 12){
    time = string.format("%d:00 %s", progressValue - 12, "PM");
}
else if(progressValue == 12){
    time = "12:00 PM";
}
else{
    time = string.format("%d:00 %s", progressValue , "AM");
}
```