# String to Current Date Time formation

Tags: java, android, date, arraylist

I am getting response from server string for Time . How to convert that string into Date . My Response String is like this **January 2, 2010** . Now i want to convert it into 02/01/2010. After converting try to make a **ArrayList** which is sorted date wise.

Comment: Have you tried using the Android Calendar class?

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html

Comment: maybe this [stack over flow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android) is what you need

Comment: I've used Date() . How can i use calender Class ?

Comment: You would need to import it using `import java.util.Calendar;`. You can then set variables as Calendar types using, for example, `Calendar dateSet= Calendar.getInstance();`

The Android documentation will tell you a lot more about what you can do with Calendar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the System time use :

`long timeInMs = System.currentTimeMillis();`

Then you can bring it in the format you want