# Getting the current date/time on an android device

Tags: android

How can I get the current date/time of an **android device**? Whether it's correct or not, doesn't matter, it just need the date/time which which is happens to be set on the android device.

I've tried this:

```
new Time().setToNow()
```

but it hasn't given me the current date/time, instead it's set it.

Comment: Get current time in milliseconds, `System.currentTimeMillis()` http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/java/lang/System.html#currentTimeMillis()

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get current time and date on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting the current date time can be done in several ways.

**Option 1**

`System.currentTimeMillis()` will return current datetime in Milliseconds.

if your parse this into Date object

```
Date newDate  = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

newDate.toString();  //This will print the Human Readable String
```

**Option 2**

```
SimpleDateFormat format= new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ",Locale.getDefault());

String myDate = format.format(new Date());
```

**Format Example**

```
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1969-12-31
                 yyyy-MM-dd 1970-01-01
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1969-12-31 16:00
           yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm 1970-01-01 00:00
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1969-12-31 16:00-0800
          yyyy-MM-dd HH:mmZ 1970-01-01 00:00+0000
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31 16:00:00.000-0800
   yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000+0000
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1969-12-31T16:00:00.000-0800
 yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ 1970-01-01T00:00:00.000+0000
```

Read more about [SimpleDateFormat](http://developer.android.com/intl/ko/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can Use this function to get Current Date and Time:

```
Date date = new Date();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this.

```
String mydate = java.text.DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance().format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```

Which output are this,

```
Oct 24, 2015 5:41:23 PM
```