# How to implement time on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, timer

I am working on Android application. Suppose a clock that show going time. Now I want to add real time that is like a clock.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle bd) {
    if (MyDebug.LOG) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
    }
    long time_s = System.currentTimeMillis();
    super.onCreate(bd);
     this.preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    }
  }
```

Comment: use a count down timer

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextClock.html http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AnalogClock.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want only current time with AM/PM then use following:

```
String current_time = (String) DateFormat.format("hh:mm aaa", Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
```