# how to convert timestamp to date for recyclerview using Kotlin, Firebase android studio

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I have a working recyclerView that shows timestamp values I need to see the date and time if possible. I am fetching data from Firebase's real-time database

this is my database
[image: database]

this is my fragment

```
private fun getIncomeData() {
    val id = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
    dref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Incomes").child(id)

    dref.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            if (snapshot.exists()){
                for (incomeSnapshot in snapshot.children){
                    val income = incomeSnapshot.getValue(IncomeItemModel::class.java)
                    incomeList.add(income!!)

                    val str = incomeSnapshot.child("incomeAmount").getValue(String::class.java)!!

                    val value = str.toInt()

                    totalIncome += value
                }
                income.text = totalIncome.toString()

                incomeRecycler.adapter = incomeAdapter
            }
        }

        override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
            TODO("Not yet implemented")
        }

    })

}
```

I can even accept the best way to insert the current time and date in the firebase database just to complete my project

this is my Adapter

```
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): IncomeViewHolder {
    val inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
    val v = DataBindingUtil.inflate<IncomeItemBinding>(
        inflater, R.layout.income_item, parent, false
    )

    return IncomeViewHolder(v)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: IncomeViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val newList = incomeList[position]

    holder.v.isIncome = incomeList[position]

    holder.v.root.setOnClickListener{
        val incomeAmount = newList.incomeAmount
        val incomeCategory = newList.incomeCategory
        val incomeNote = newList.incomeNote
        val incomeDate = newList.incomeDate


    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return incomeList.size
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

just read stored timestamp and convert it to `long`

```
val dateAsString = incomeSnapshot.child("incomeDate").getValue(String::class.java)!!
val dateAsLong = dateAsString.toLong()
```

looks like your value is in milliseconds already (as Android operates with such precision) and convert to Date, then format it

```
private fun getDateTimeAsFormattedString(dateAsLongInMs: Long): String? {
    try {
        return SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm").format(Date(dateAsLongInMs))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        return null // parsing exception
    }
}
```

more samples how to convert in [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47250263/kotlin-convert-timestamp-to-datetime)

use `getDateTimeAsFormattedString` in e.g. adapter for printing date on every list item. timestamps are probably already parsed in `incomeList`

Comment: thank you very much for your response but still, I failed to implement it in my adapter. I have edited my question and added my adapter codes can you start from there

Comment: sadly no, your adapter is so much empty, there is no `View`s for set text, no source of `R.layout.income_item`, no `IncomeViewHolder` and `IconItemModel` models, but there is `OnClickListener` set, which does nothing... (gets some values from model only, doing nothing with them) Looks like your code is far from working/presenting, very UNfinished... I've already answered to posted question, my job is done, now yours is to finish rest of your project

Answer (score 0):

Here is a similar question with an answer [FirebaseTimestampToTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72489046/i-have-managed-to-retrieve-timestamp-from-firebase-of-each-post-but-how-to-i-cap/72572538#72572538)

Hope it works for you.