# Can not parse time into correct GMT

Tags: android, kotlin, parsing, time

From API i get time as string "13:00:00Z" in this format and it is GMT 0 time zone.

I want to adjust it to my time zone which is GMT +4.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36860468/how-to-convert-utc-date-to-locale-gmt-time-on-android

Answer (score 1):

First you convert time into utc then after convert utc time to  your local time zone. like example:

```
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
                    simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                    try {
                        Date utcDate = simpleDateFormat.parse("Your date");
                        SimpleDateFormat yourDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy · HH'h'mm", Locale.getDefault());
                        String dateString = simpleDateFormat.format(utcDate);
                        binding.orderdate.setText(dateString);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```