# How do i get current system time in android?

Tags: java, android

I need to read a bluetooth stream for 5 seconds, because I need to be sure my app will get the bluetooth message (which is actually just a `char` casted to `int`).
If my app can't read the message my `btState` variable is set to a certain value for another task.

```
while(btState!=666)
{
  btState=666;
    try {                       
        while(timestart-timenow<5){ //how do i do this?
            btState=mConnectThread.checkstate();
            mConnectThread.sendSignal('s');
         }
    } catch (Exception e) {break; }
}
```

Comment: "How do i get current system time in android?" -- `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: @Lucas please next time try googling first! https://www.google.at/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=get+current+time+android

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

`Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int seconds = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);`

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) for the Calendar class

Have a look at this thread: [Get current time and date on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android) that asks pretty much the same question for more suggestions.

Credits to user658042 for the answer.