# Time based actions or texts

Tags: android, android-studio, text, time

I am trying to make an app for students, and in the home screen of the app I would like to display a message like "Hey! Good Morning" and it should change to "Hey!Good evening" when it is after 15:00hrs of a day and so on.
How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Use system, i.e mobile, time. see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this one.It may help you.

```
      Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int timeOfDay = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

        if(timeOfDay >= 0 && timeOfDay < 12){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Morning", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();        
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 12 && timeOfDay < 16){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Afternoon", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 16 && timeOfDay < 21){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Evening", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(timeOfDay >= 21 && timeOfDay < 24){
            Toast.makeText(this, "Good Night", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get the time or hour by

```
import java.util.Calendar

Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); 
int hours = c.get(Calendar.HOUR);
```

from this you can choose a String for your textview:

```
TextView mytextview=(TextView) findViewByID(...);
String message="";
if(hours<11){
message="good morning"
}else if(hours>=11 & hours<17){
message=...}
mytextview.setText(message);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place a check for time of day in your activity in `onResume()`. This will check whenever the screen which has to display the text comes to foreground. So, even when you return to it from a different screen, the check will be made. For realtime check you will need a mechanism for absolute callback of the event [of 1500 hrs].

This might be a bit cumbersome and we need more info to decide on a mechanism. You should also decide if this is exactly what you want to do or not.

Not showing checking code because of its trivial nature.