# Get default timezone in android

Tags: java, android, android-calendar, android-date

I need to get local time in my app. I am using Calendar class for this purpose.

Code :

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
```

`calendar.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` shows the hours according to GMT.

I checked that `TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()` shows GMT (which is incorrect) as default timezone but `java.util.TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName()` shows the correct timezone.
Also `calendar.getTime().toString()` shows the correct time.

I do not understand why there is this discrepancy between `android.icu.util.TimeZone` and `java.util.TimeZone`

Edit:

I recently found that there are two Calendar APIs - java.util.Calendar (added in API level 1) and android.icu.util.Calendar (added in API level 24).

I had been using android.icu.util.Calendar but tested it on Android M. So now I'll be using API java.util.Calendar

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android

Comment: @NabinKhadka I am getting time for GMT timezone. But my requirement is to get time for local timezone.

Comment: you can use TimeZone.getDefault() it gives you default time zone and calendar instance by default picks default time zone

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the below:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30")); //If you are seeking local time of India
```

Or

```
date.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+05:30")); 

String localTime = date.format(currentLocalTime); //To get current local time
```

Comment: I need the timezone to be variable depending upon user's location. Android documentation suggests to use TimeZone.getDefault() for this purpose, but it is not working in my case.

Comment: You can try long currentTime = new Date().getTime(); It will give time of the device. Hence, User's time in whichever zone he is

Comment: I'm completely unable to get the local time zone on any device i connect to Androids studio and use TimeZone.getDefault(). I always get GMT time with gmt Offset being 0.  Anyone know how to get the real timezone in api 22 and above?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
String.format("GMT %.2f", TimeZone.getDefault()).replace(",", ".")
```

Also you can get the time zone that you want in this way:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
```

For more details check documentation here: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimeZone