# Getting previous selected date on CalendarDatePicker android

Tags: java, android, better-pickers

I'm trying to figure out how to get the current selected date to be showned on the CalendarDatePicker. `E.g.` If i have September 13, 2016 as the date being selected it should be shown/highlighted on the CalendarDatePicker that i selected that date. So i set the date and display it on a textview, and if I update the date it should get the previous selected date being highligted on the CalendarDatePicker. I've added their onDayOfMonthSelected() method but it still not working. This is  what i have so far. I'm using this library [Android-BetterPicker](https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpicker) from github.

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment cdp2 = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment()
                        .setOnDateSetListener(CalendarPicker.this);
                cdp2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
                cdp2.setOnDateSetListener(new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        mResultTextView.setText(getString(R.string.calendar_date_picker_result_values, year, monthOfYear+1, dayOfMonth));
                    }
                });
            }
});
```

Here's my onResume() function

```
public void onResume() {
        // Example of reattaching to the fragment
        super.onResume();
        CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment calendarDatePickerDialogFragment = (CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
        if (calendarDatePickerDialogFragment != null) {
            calendarDatePickerDialogFragment.onDayOfMonthSelected(CHOSEN_YEAR,CHOSEN_MONTH,CHOSEN_DAY);
            calendarDatePickerDialogFragment.setOnDateSetListener(this);
        }
}
```

Comment: Do you use any special library for that dialog ?!

Comment: try with This code This Code must Help you [Click on This Link you can use dat time with your way this is custom way of date and time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android/34328449#34328449)

Comment: Try with This Link. [Click here to read more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android/34328449#34328449)

Comment: I'm using this library [github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers](http://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have a function for what you want :

```
public void onResume() {
    // Example of reattaching to the fragment
    super.onResume();
    CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment calendarDatePickerDialogFragment = (CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);
    if (calendarDatePickerDialogFragment != null) {
        calendarDatePickerDialogFragment.onDayOfMonthSelected(CHOSEN_YEAR,CHOSEN_MONTH,CHOSEN_DAY);
        calendarDatePickerDialogFragment.setOnDateSetListener(this);
    }
}
```

also change here :

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment cdp2 = new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment()
                    .setOnDateSetListener(CalendarPicker.this);


            cdp2.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), FRAG_TAG_DATE_PICKER);

            //here
            cdp2.onDayOfMonthSelected(CHOSEN_YEAR,CHOSEN_MONTH,CHOSEN_DAY);

            cdp2.setOnDateSetListener(new CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment.OnDateSetListener() {

                @Override
                public void onDateSet(CalendarDatePickerDialogFragment dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                    mResultTextView.setText(getString(R.string.calendar_date_picker_result_values, year, monthOfYear+1, dayOfMonth));
                }
            });
        }
});
```

Comment: What do you exactly want to do ?
just get the last chosen date ? or mark last chosen date on calendar ? @Nube1Nu2

Comment: getting the last chosen date. The last chosen date should be now selected  on the picker before picking another date.

Comment: Everytime I selected the picker it always gets back on the current date today not on the last chosen date

Comment: Im getting java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Do date setting after showing the fragment. see my edited answer again. i edited it again @Nube1Nu2

Answer (score 0):

You can this :

```
 DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker1);
 int day = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();
 int month = datePicker.getMonth() + 1;
 int year = datePicker.getYear();
```

If you want to show the current date on Button itself, then use this one :

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        MyDate mydate = new MyDate();

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            if (getArguments()!=null && getArguments().get("DATE") != null) {
                mydate = (MyDate) getArguments().get("DATE");
            }

            DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, mydate.year, mydate.month, mydate.day);

            dpd.getDatePicker().setCalendarViewShown(false);
            dpd.setTitle("Set Date");
            return dpd;
        }

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            mydate = new MyDate(day,month,year);
            if (getTag().equals("birthdatePicker")){
                birthday.setText(mydate.toStringDate());
            }
            else if (getTag().equals("annidatePicker")){
                anniversary.setText(mydate.toStringDate());
            }
            else if (getTag().equals("spousedatePicker")){
                spousebday.setText(mydate.toStringDate());
            }
        }

        public String getDate(){
            return mydate.toString();
        }
    }

    static class MyDate implements Parcelable {
        int day;
        int month;
        int year;

        public MyDate() {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR)- 15;
            month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        }

        public MyDate(int day, int month, int year) {
            this.day = day;
            this.month = month;
            this.year = year;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return year + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + day;
        }

        public String toStringDate(){
            return day + "-" + (month+1) + "-" + year;
        }

        public static MyDate toDate(String date) {
            String [] strArray = date.split("/");
            int d = Integer.parseInt(strArray[0]);
            int m = Integer.parseInt(strArray[1])-1;
            int y = Integer.parseInt(strArray[2]);
            return new MyDate(d, m, y);
        }

        @Override
        public int describeContents() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeInt(this.day);
            dest.writeInt(this.month);
            dest.writeInt(this.year);
        }

        protected MyDate(Parcel in) {
            this.day = in.readInt();
            this.month = in.readInt();
            this.year = in.readInt();
        }

        public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyDate> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyDate>() {
            @Override
            public MyDate createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
                return new MyDate(source);
            }

            @Override
            public MyDate[] newArray(int size) {
                return new MyDate[size];
            }
        };
    }


public void showBirthDateDialog() {
    birthFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "birthdatePicker");
}


birthday.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showBirthDateDialog();
        }
    });
```

I think this will help your cause !