# Current time is not shown properly

Tags: android, kotlin

The current date and year shows correctly but is not shown properly
The time should show properly 
The code is in kotlin. Could anyone help me out with the solution ?

```
object DateTimeHelper {

    private fun formatDate(date: String): Date? {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
        sdf.timeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")
        var dateIn: Date?
        dateIn = try {
            sdf.parse(date)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Timber.e(e)
            null
        }

        return dateIn
    }


    fun getDate(date: String): String {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat(" MMM dd, yyyy")
        val tz = TimeZone.getDefault()
        sdf.timeZone = tz
        return sdf.format(formatDate(date))
    }

    fun getTime(date: String): String {
        val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aaa")
        val tz = TimeZone.getDefault()
        sdf.timeZone = tz
        return sdf.format(formatDate(date))
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by not shown properly

Comment: I mean it is not showing the correct time , if the time is 18.30 it shows 2.30

Comment: why are you passing a date if you want to get the current date

Comment: What should be done to get correct results ?

Comment: What do you really want to get

Comment: The correct time

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/get-current-time-and-date-on-android