# How to get current time and make it textview

Tags: java, android-studio

I'am trying to get current time and make it textview. What i find is 10 or 12 years old and i dont realy know if thats working and how it works. I saw that you can use firebase and another sites or apps for it. I'd like to get some help with it.

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5369682/how-to-get-current-time-and-date-in-android#:%7E:text=Calendar%20Date%20currentTime%20%3D%20Calendar.,getTime()%3B)

Some code i find

```
Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);

Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MINUTE);
```

Thanks all.

Comment: what is make it textview? what do you want to do?

Comment: Check following :

`long date = System.currentTimeMillis();`
`SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM MM dd, yyyy h:mm a");`
`String dateString = sdf.format(date);`
`tvDisplayDate.setText(dateString);`

This should display in the following example format

`Tue Apr 12, 2022 10:26 AM`

tvDisplayDate is text view .

For different formats of date time you can refer following link :

[Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the current Time only

```
long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
        String currentTime = simpleDateFormat.format(currentDateTime);
        Toast.makeText(this, currentTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

and if you want the Date & Time both then the below code is for you

```
        long currentDateTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy  h:mm a");
        String currentDateTime = simpleDateFormat.format(currentDateTime);
        Toast.makeText(this, currentDateTime, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

EDIT 1
another method to do this

```
LocalDateTime myDt= LocalDateTime.now();
        Toast.makeText(this, myDt.getHour()+":"+myDt.getMinute()+":"+myDt.getSecond(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

EDIT 2
another method to get Date only

```
LocalDateTime myDt= LocalDateTime.now();
        DateTimeFormatter newDt = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE;
        String dates = newDt.format(myDt);
        Toast.makeText(this,dates, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You can get more options to get a date, time, GMT, or more by changing from  `ISO_DATE` to `ISO_DATE_TIME`, `ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME` etc.

Comment: I have 2 problems with SimpleDateFormat and format this two are red for me. On simpleDateFormat i have "Cannot resolve symbol 'SimpleDateFormat' " error and on format i have "Cannot resolve method 'format(long)' ". Maybe i need any implementation in gradle?

Comment: @DaniilNedbaylo Ok, use this method-> `LocalDateTime myDt= LocalDateTime.now();
        Toast.makeText(this, myDt.getHour()+":"+myDt.getMinute()+":"+myDt.getSecond(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        System.out.println(myDt.getHour()+":"+myDt.getMinute()+":"+myDt.getSecond());`

Comment: Thanks thats works do you have any idea for date?

Comment: @DaniilNedbaylo yah why not. I added the date code in my answer.